# Iframe приложение Вконтакте.

Tags: vkontakte-api

Пробую создать программу Вконтакте ... JS еще плохо знаю ... Все вроде делаю по официальной документации, но так ничего и не получается ...

---

Вот код:

```
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

VK.init(function() {
    VK.callMethod("setTitle", 'DemoApp');
    VK.api('users.get',{uids: '15547040'},function(data) { 
      if (data.error) { 
      alert('error!'+data.error);
      }
      if (data.response) {
        alert('good!'+data.response);
      } 
    });  
});

function pravadostupa () {
    VK.callMethod("showSettingsBox", 8707);
}

function friendaddf () {
    VK.callMethod("showInviteBox");
}

</script>
```

---

Колл Методы работают отлично, но API не работает! Что я делаю не так? Хочу научиться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Ваше приложение не опубликовано и оно имеет статус "Отключено", то необходимо добавлять флаг `test_mode` равный 1, пример:

```
VK.api('isAppUser',{test_mode: test_mode},function(data) {
   if (data.error)
      alert(data.error.error_msg);
   else if (data.response) {
      alert(data.response);
   }
});
```